# Browser not prompting for certificate - IIS 10.0

Tags: iis, iis-10

0

I have an application that was working fine in IIS 8.5 which used this setting in the web.config file for a client certificate login (smartcard) for a path. I had to migrate this application to IIS 10.0 and everything is working except the application does not prompt for the certificate and just simply throws an error in the code that there is no certificate.

I have double checked and triple checked all the settings in IIS, the certificate is the same, the SSL settings are the same. The application is a simple .netcore application and it works perfectly with the exception of the certificate prompt. Is there something that is different in IIS 10 than 8.5 that I could be missing. The portion of the web.config that enables the browser to prompt the certificate I believe is this part here. The developer who did this is not longer with us and I would appreciate any help for this. Is there something that I need to check in IIS other than what I have already checked?

I went through some other posts and made sure that the root and intermediary certificate are in the cert store etc. The app itself loads fine with the SSL certificate.

```
<location path="SmartCard">
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <access sslFlags="Ssl,SslNegotiateCert" />
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: You need `SslRequireCert` instead of `SslNegotiateCert`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/access#configuration

Comment: I tried that, it still does not prompt for the cert. It simply gives me unauthorized access error.

Comment: The browser won't prompt if it finds only a single valid client certificate to use, or none. So when you see an unauthorized access error, make sure you know the exact HTTP status code/substatus code from IIS log files, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/http-status-code That's just the beginning of your troubleshooting.

Comment: I have three certificates and the current deployment on 8.5 shows the browser popup with the option to choose. But in IIS 10 it just seems to ignore the certificates altogether

Comment: How did yoiu migrate the application from IIS8.5 to 10? I think something wrong happened during migration.